# Why is 0022FF08 + sizeof(int) = 0022FF0C instead of 0022FF0A?

Tags: c++, c, hex, codeblocks

`char` is 1 byte incremnt. `int` is 2 byte increment. `float` is 4 byte increment. `double` is 8 byte increment. why int increase **4 byte** here?

[image: Hex Increment Program]

[image: Hex Increment Output]

Comment: Who says an `int` is necessary 2 bytes? On your system (and most), it is 4.

Comment: Your premise is wrong. Problem solved.

Comment: Please insert the code as a text.

Comment: @GManNickG so, int and float increment is 4?

Comment: @SpacezLyWang: According to the language, the increment is `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(float)` respectively. On your particular system, that means 4 for both.

Comment: @Andrey , I can't use stackoverflow editor well. that's why i uploaded pics

Comment: possible duplicate of [size of int, long, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc)

Comment: What is your trouble with the editor? It's bad practice to attach screenshots in SO because a screenshot is not searchable and not editable.

Comment: It is a real shame since this is one of the better editors I have seen with instant feedback and good help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int` is 32 bits, so is `float`.  Here, `double` is 64 bits.

On many 16-bit systems, `int` is 16 bits.  C's `int` was intended to be whatever size is most natural for the system it is compiled for.  There is no requirement that `int` be the same size across systems.

Comment: ...on most architectures used nowadays! This wasn't evident a few decades ago. Maybe he just learnt from an outdated book...

Comment: @ppeterka yes, i'm reading a book from old age. You've pointed out. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
int i;
...
printf("%d",sizeof(i));
```

What did you get? Most likely 4. Why? Because your CPU is most likely a 32bit one. The 2 byte int was true on older CPUs...

Never assume sizes of variables based on "should be", always use sizeof()!